# How to select elements based on xy coordinates, not using  mouse drag, with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, selectable

How to select elements based on XY coordinates and not with mouse drag with jquery?
[image]

Comment: Should elements which are partially within that range be selected?

Comment: no, just those that are completely selected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery plugin, as shown below, will select all elements which are (partially) at position >= x and >= y.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.filterXY = function(x, y){
        return this.filter(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                offset = $this.offset(),
                width = $this.width(),
                height = $this.height();
            return offset.left + width >= x
                && offset.top + height >= y;
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Examples:

```
$("*").filterXY(0,0);
$("div").filterXY(100, 0);
```

---

### Update: Plugin to filter all elements between x1 and x2

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yx4sN/7/**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.inRangeX = function(x1, x2){
        // Accepting selectors and DOM elements
        if (typeof x1 == "string" && +x1 != x1 || x1 instanceof Element) {
            x1 = $(x1);
        }
        if (typeof x2 == "string" && +x1 != x1 || x1 instanceof Element) {
            x2 = $(x2);
        }
        // Accepting jQuery objects
        if (x1 instanceof $) {
            x1 = x1.offset().left;
        }
        if (x2 instanceof $) {
            x2 = x2.offset().left;
        }
        x1 = +x1;
        x2 = +x2;

        // Make sure that x1 < x2
        if (x1 > x2) {
            var x = x1;
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = x;
        }
        return this.filter(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                offset = $this.offset(),
                rightSide = $this.width() + offset.left;
            return offset.left >= x1
                  && rightSide <= x2;
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: can you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/ingol/yx4sN/, where would i need to implement yours solution?

Comment: it always returns 99, as the sum of child elements, how to achieve that it returns only sum of elements on right of firstPicker and smaller(left) than secondPicker

Comment: thanks, can you explain how automaticly select those child elements that are in xy scope, using selectable()?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5740/discussion-between-rob-w-and-ingol)

Comment: After some discussion, the final, desired solution is constructed, and can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ingol/yx4sN/9/

Comment: ,can you take a look at this question, please? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8473404/765628

Comment: @Ingol I'm currently busy. I will check out your question later.