# How to prevent draggable child elements from dragging over each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, collision-detection, jquery-ui-draggable

How to prevent draggable child elements from dragging over each other in absolute position?
Something like:

```
if( ($("#firstChild").position().left) >= ($("#secondChild").position().left) )
{
    $(this).draggable({ disabled: true });
}
```

but this only disables dragabble when stop dragging, the goal is to prevent from *overdragging* in some way...Or with Droppable???

[image]

Any ideas for CASE 2?

**EDIT:**

Also, this is maximum for *child1* towards *child2* , so **no overlap occurs**, but *child1* can push *child2* on right, and *child2* can push *child1* on left, important thing is that no overlap ocurrs!

Comment: Could you provide a test case? I don't have enough time to collect all relevant code in order to create a test case.

Comment: @RobW , http://jsfiddle.net/ingol/rmaU2/

Comment: Check this out...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482388/jquery-draggable-no-overlap

Comment: @Rob W, I provided test case, did you had time to check it out?

Comment: Finished creating reliable code, going to construct an answer now. The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rmaU2/90/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes before / in order to reach the optimal solution:

- You have declared and initialised the `allBetween` variablw, but not using it. I suggest to remove it.
- At your `#buttonOne` event listener, you're using inconsistent values: 429 and 424: `if($("#firstInput").val() > 429 )$("#firstInput").val(424);`

  1. You're using the `#firstInput` (and `#thirdInput`) selector multiple times without caching a reference.
  2. You're duplicating the functions for each button. A better, less error-prone solution is to create a method to build these methods.

### Final code

The optimisations have been explained previously. I will not elaborate them, since that's not the topic of the question. I have explained the function logic of the requested behavior in the scripts comments (below).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Helper to easily bind related events to the button.
    function createButtonClickEvent(sel_selector, input_selector, left_limit, right_limit) {
        return function(){
            var $sel = $(sel_selector),
                $input = $(input_selector),
                val = $input.val();
            if (val > right_limit) input.val(val = right_limit);
            else if (val < left_limit) input.val(val = left_limit);
            $sel.css('left', val + "px");

            var $allElems = $("#second").children(".single"),
                 $between = $allElems.inRangeX("#selFirst", "#selSecond");
            $allElems.removeClass("ui-selected");
            $between.addClass("ui-selected");
        }
    }
       //setValue 1
    $("#buttonOne").click(createButtonClickEvent("#selFirst", "#firstInput", 0, 429));    
    //setValue2
    $("#buttonTwo").click(createButtonClickEvent("#selSecond", "#thirdInput", 0, 429));


    //graph values
    var valuesG = [],
        $elements = $();
    for (i = 0; i < 144; i++) {
        valuesG[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 20 + 1) + 10);
        $elements = $elements.add($("<div class='single'>")
                             .css('height', valuesG[i])
                             .css('margin-top', 30 - valuesG[i]));
    }
    $elements.appendTo($("#second"));
    $("#second").children(".single").addClass("ui-selected");

    //inRangeX (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8457155/938089)
    (function($) {
        $.fn.inRangeX = function(x1, x2) {

            if (typeof x1 == "string" && +x1 != x1 || x1 instanceof Element) {
                x1 = $(x1);
            }
            if (typeof x2 == "string" && +x1 != x1 || x1 instanceof Element) {
                x2 = $(x2);
            }

            if (x1 instanceof $) {
                x1 = x1.offset().left;
            }
            if (x2 instanceof $) {
                x2 = x2.offset().left;
            }
            x1 = +x1;
            x2 = +x2;


            if (x1 > x2) {
                var x = x1;
                x1 = x2;
                x2 = x;
            }
            return this.filter(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    offset = $this.offset(),
                    rightSide = offset.left - 5;
                return offset.left >= x1 + 5 && rightSide <= x2;
            });
        }
    })(jQuery);

    //firstPositions
    var startFirst = $(".selector#selFirst").position().left;
    var startSecond = $(".selector#selSecond").position().left;
    $('input#firstInput').val(startFirst);
    $('input#thirdInput').val(startSecond);

    // *********** Actual requested code *********** //
    //first and second-Picker
    var $selFirst = $("#selFirst"),
        $selSecond = $("#selSecond"),
        cachedWidth = $selFirst.outerWidth();

    function drag_function(event, ui){
        var $firstRightBorder = $selFirst.position().left + cachedWidth,
             $secondLeft = $selSecond.position().left,
             diff = $firstRightBorder - $secondLeft;
        /*
         * The logic is as follows:
         * dif < 0 if selFirst and selSecond do not overlap
         * dif = 0 if they're next to each other
         * dif > 0 if they overlap each other
         * To fix this (reminder: if they overlap, dif is negative):
         * If current == #selFirst,
         *    left = left + dif
         * else (if current == #selSecond),
         *    left = left - dif
         */
        if (diff > 0) {
            var currentLeft = parseFloat($(this).css("left"));
            if (this.id == "selSecond") diff = -diff;
            ui.position.left = currentLeft - diff;
            ui.helper.css("left", currentLeft - diff);
        }
        var $allElems = $("#second").children(".single"),
            $between = $allElems.inRangeX("#selFirst", "#selSecond");
        $("#firstInput").val($("#selFirst").position().left);
        $("#thirdInput").val($("#selSecond").position().left);
        $allElems.removeClass("ui-selected");
        $between.addClass("ui-selected");
        var allBetween = $('.ui-selected');
    }

    $("#selFirst, #selSecond").draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        axis: 'x',
        drag: drag_function,
        stop: drag_function
    });
}); //eof
```

Comment: I guess that I'm late, you have already found a good answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use gamequery plugin. theres a collision detection.

second thing you can do is: when you hover your element while dragging... just trigger drop ? so he will never be able to drag it inside. make something like drag position of mouse at the right of the dragged element so you are sure thats not possible to drag it inside this element.

i hope you know what i mean

example calling drop:

```
$('#rightbox').live('mouseenter', function(){
  $('#leftbox').droppable.option('drop');
});
```

something like that... havent test it but its a way to start with

Comment: do you have any examples of this solution?