# Get div at different z-index but same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Div which is positioned via javascript.

```
$("#'+customer.Id+'").css({
        left: customerOffset,
        width: customerWidth- endDayOffset,
        height: document.getElementById("Planning").rows[0].clientHeight,
        display: "normal",
        position: "absolute"
    });
    $("#'+customer.Id+'").offset({ top: bottomTop })
```

This div is placed on a table cell with a certain Id.
This Id I want to obtain.
How is this possible?

Comment: You're trying to get the ID of the element that this is being appended to? Where's the code you use to append this element.

Comment: "placed on a table cell" = over top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery `.parents()` method to find the ancestor table cell.

```
$("#'+customer.Id+'").parents("td#' + tableCell.Id + '");
```

Turns out you're asking about similar coordinates.

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457082/how-to-select-elements-based-on-xy-coordinates-not-using-mouse-drag-with-jque) might be able to help you.

Comment: I just re-read your question.  When you say on top of a table cell, do you mean the html is within that table cell, or it just looks like it's on top of it?

Comment: I think the poster is looking for the element where the coordinates overlap, not the DOM tree position.

Comment: [This might be able to help him](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457082/how-to-select-elements-based-on-xy-coordinates-not-using-mouse-drag-with-jque)

Comment: Yes Diodeus, thats what I meant. Because the div isn't placed inside the html of the table cell. The link of Steinmas helped me. Thanks